# Reduce the SYS_LOB file in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-xe

I have expanded the table space to Oracle, 9 GB in size. But faced with the problem a few months later, the file SYS_LOB0000098796C00006 $$ took 8.5 GB (and 500 MB left for different index tables and so on). I save the photo on the server (via UTL_FILE), not in the table space. What can be done with this file to reduce it ??? I will be grateful for the help).

I write imafe on server:

```html
  V_JSON64   := apex_json.get_clob (p_values => json_table, p_path => 'snapshot', p0 => 3); 
  V_SNAPSHOT := iot_general.clob_base64_to_blob (p_clob => V_JSON64); 


 v_date_id := lower(common_functionality.new_uuid);
  v_length  := DBMS_LOB.getlength(V_SNAPSHOT) ;
  v_filename_date :=  v_filename ||  v_date_id ;
  v_file := UTL_FILE.fopen('CDN',v_filename_date , 'wb', 32767);
  WHILE v_index <= v_length LOOP
    v_bytecount := 32767;
    DBMS_LOB.read(V_SNAPSHOT, v_bytecount, v_index, v_tempraw);
    UTL_FILE.put_raw(v_file,v_tempraw);
    UTL_FILE.fflush(v_file);
    v_index := v_index + v_bytecount;
  END LOOP;
  UTL_FILE.fclose(v_file);
```

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example ? which commands did you use for the table and the blob insert ?

Comment: @RobertoHernandez Yes, I added code in which I get a photo in base 64 format, and then write that photo to the server. In order not to clog the tabular space of the oracle.